# Ubuntu Software Application

Tags: software-installation, software-center, software-uninstall

When I try to remove an application from the Ubuntu Software application it tells me there is no packages to remove, but when I do dpk - l | grep  it's still there. Will there be a fix for this soon, because I prefer removing packages from the application rather than CLI. I am running on Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop.

Comment: Care to share which application you are trying to remove? Background: Ubuntu 22.04 tries to force "snap" apps (with all its caveats) over deb packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using GNOME Software instead:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

This will list your `deb` packages.

Optionally, install the following to add snap and flatpak support to GNOME Software:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-snap
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
```